# How to get the redirection status of a Ruby script (write/append/pipe)

Tags: ruby, bash, redirect, append, stdout

My Ruby script maintains an m3u format playlist, which begins with a header:

```
#EXTM3U
```

Then some title and artist information comes, and next the URL or file path, as follows:

```
#EXTINF:0, Echo tv Terrorellenes akcióterv Echo Tv 16 perc 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qxmpXHL6j74
```

All in all example:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:0, echo tv Terrorellenes akcióterv   Echo Tv 16 perc 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qxmpXHL6j74
#EXTINF:0, echo tv Energiahatékonyság   Echo Tv 6 perc  34 másodperc 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q8fZ7bo4gZo
#EXTINF:0, echo tv Jöhet a kvótanépszavazás   Echo Tv 23 perc 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zkgIL1LXldI
```

My script simply writes its output to `STDOUT`, and I redirect it to an .m3u playlist file. Sometimes, I just want to append the output to an existing playlist file, and in such case, I would like to omit the header, and just let the remaining content be written into the m3u file. For this reason, I would like to detect in my script whether `STDOUT` is redirected with writing (`>`) or appending (`>>`) mode so that I can choose whether to print the `#EXTM3U` header or not. How can I detect that status of the `STDOUT` object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can check if `STDOUT` is empty before writing:

```
% ruby -e 'puts File.zero?(STDOUT)' > test01
% cat test01
true
% ruby -e 'puts File.zero?(STDOUT)' >> test02
% cat test02
true
% ruby -e 'puts File.zero?(STDOUT)' >> test02
% cat test02
true
false
```

Note that the first append will give `true` since the file is actually empty, and in that case I assume it's okay to write the header.